# How does Rails 3 load the model layer in production mode and resolve model dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, dependencies, loading

In other words, does it work similarly to development mode but caches the classes as they are required? Or are all models loaded upfront?

If the latter, how does Rails know to load a model which is a dependency (of another model) before the model which depends on it?

I'd like to know so I can evaluate how feasible it is to load Rails models into a vanilla Ruby project without using the Rails script runner.

Comment: This might get you started: http://railscasts.com/episodes/299-rails-initialization-walkthrough

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that's a pro episode for which you have to pay.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the link Thilo. Maybe I'll save up and pay for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes are required upfront. Rails basically does `require_dependency` on everything in `config.eager_load_paths`, in alphabetic order ([see here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/railties/lib/rails/engine.rb#L433)).

`require_dependency` is part of Active Support, and is in a nutshell load/require but that integrates with Active Support's dependency tracking. If during this process rails comes across something which is not already loaded (e.g. if A was a subclass of B) then the usual `const_missing` hooks will fire and load `b.rb`.

You should be able to setup Active Support like rails does and call the same methods from your non rails project.

Comment: Thanks Frederick. That's what I was looking for. Thanks a mill!